# Can't install SDL in msys2

Tags: sdl, msys2

When i run `make all` in msys2 for SDL 1.2.14, i see this:

```
/bin/sh ./libtool --mode=compile gcc -g -O2  -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -c ./src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c  -o build/SDL_RLEaccel.lo
libtool: compile:  gcc -g -O2 -I./include -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -c ./src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o build/.libs/SDL_RLEaccel.o
In file included from ./src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c:90:0:
./src/video/SDL_sysvideo.h:188:0: warning: "WINAPI" redefined
#define WINAPI
^
In file included from /usr/include/w32api/windef.h:8:0,
                 from /usr/include/w32api/windows.h:69,
                 from /usr/include/w32api/GL/gl.h:13,
                 from ./include/SDL_opengl.h:46,
                 from ./src/video/SDL_sysvideo.h:37,
                 from ./src/video/SDL_RLEaccel.c:90:
/usr/include/w32api/minwindef.h:98:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
#define WINAPI __stdcall
^
/tmp/cc6gwyDo.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc6gwyDo.s:3611: Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'
/tmp/cc6gwyDo.s:4101: Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'
/tmp/cc6gwyDo.s:4493: Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'
/tmp/cc6gwyDo.s:4969: Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'
/tmp/cc6gwyDo.s:6895: Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'
/tmp/cc6gwyDo.s:7240: Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'
/tmp/cc6gwyDo.s:7593: Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'
/tmp/cc6gwyDo.s:8125: Error: operand type mismatch for `movq'
make: *** [build-deps:536: build/SDL_RLEaccel.lo] Error 1
```

./configure finished with no errors (details [here](https://pastebin.com/BbdzarcG)) What's wrong? And how can i compile it?

Comment: Looks like you're using the msys-2.0.dll-based toolchain instead of the mingw-w64 toolchain which makes native Windows apps.  Do you know about the different MSYS2 toolchains and MSYS2 shells?  Also, why build SDL instead of just installing the MSYS2 package for it?

Comment: I don't know much about MSYS2 or MinGW. I just want to build Dosbox-X on Windows and someone said i need MSYS2 to do it. So i installed MSYS2 and installed a few tools like git with it's package manager. I didn't know there's an MSYS2 package for SDL. Would you please tell it's name and where can i get it? Because running `pacman -Q | grep sdl` didn't return anything. On Ubuntu i the package i needed was `libsdl1.2-dev`.

Comment: Try `pacman -Ss | grep SDL`

Comment: Thanks. I found a few packages this way and installed one, but it was not what i needed to compile dosbox-x. But that's for another question.